# Alternative to legacy tabs parent set in current navigation menu in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

Just like we could make parent tab set and combine all tabs in it.
Is it possible to do the same with navigation menus?
Basically, how can we convert set of tabs to navigation menus explicitly?

or create a parent list that would contain all the other lists.
Ex: Manager list, employee list all could get combined to one parent list,
Is this possible?

In shot, how can we convert the standard tab set in navigation menu format?

Comment: Wow, I hardly remember tabs. Why not just play around with navigation menus to see if they meet your needs. They should work great! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vini,
Within Lists you can develop structures as many levels deep as you like. To do so just specify the parent list entry.
One customer that comes to mind has a single Navigation Menu list with several hundred entries, numerous levels deep.
With APEX 20.1 you now have the choice of displaying the Navigation Menu on the side, on the top or as a Mega Menu.
Regards,
David